# Full-text-search in a xml file with java (with Xpath?)

Tags: java, xml, xpath, full-text-search

is there a possibility to perform a full text search in a xml file with Xpath and select them using java? I want to select all elements (no mater if it is a comment, node or attribute), which contains a special word. For example:
Searching for "bob" I would like to get tag1, bob1 and tag3 as a result

```
<tag1 name="bob">
    <tag2/>
    <bob1/>
    <tag3 bob="true"/>
</tag1>
```

If it is possible, I prefer a solution without using an external package.
I would be very happy if somebody could help me. I couldn't find anything like this until now. Thank you very much!
Kind regards

EDIT: I am searching for a possibility to finde every occurrence of the word "Bob", no matter what function Bob has!

Comment: So, you also want to extract *all subnodes* under the matching node? It smells like a bad pattern. I think that further studying your XML you could have more specific solution.

Comment: I hoped that maybe there is a general solution so that I dont have to make an assumptions... Thank you for your comment!

Comment: General solutions are never effective. It really pays off to study your problem domain, occasionally you will make mistakes later because of ignoring some basic fact.

Comment: Something like //*[@name='bob']? You might want to keep [XPath tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) on hand ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a simple SAX parser to process your XML. Here's the [Oracle SAX tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html) for starting.

You can go through all nodes, mark (and save) those nodes that are interesting for you, and return the resulting nodes as a new XML document, or String, or whatever form you want.

Comment: I didnt want to iterate through the whole document and I hoped to do it with Xpath, but apparently it´s not possible. Thank you for your Answer.

Answer (score 1):

XPath defines the contains() function (see http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains) which you could use in an expression like:

```
//*[contains(., "wordtosearchfor")]
```

which would find all elements containing the word

To find all attributes containing the word, you could use:

```
//*[@*[contains(., "wordtosearchfor")]]
```

which would find all elements having an attribute containing the word

However the problem as you stated it is not well-posed.  The XML sample you gave is not well-formed, and it is not true that  contains "bob".  So it's hard to tell exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hallo,
thank you for you help.
I know that it is not true that "bob1" and "tag3" contain "bob", but I'm searching a possibility to do it: I want something like a Full-Text-Search within a String (like I would parse the whole xml to a string) with the possibilty to select the element which has the string that I'm searching for.
PS: sorry that the xml was not well-formed (I didn't know how the use the editor at stackoverflow...)